# Spring AntPathMatcher behave differently when pattern last char is '/'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The spring version I used is 4.3.7-SNAPSHOT and The default path separator is **/**

I found that when patter string last char is '**/**', while path string last char is NOT '**/**', the AntPathMatcher behave differently, please see the code below

```
public class AntPathMatcher4SpringTest {

private AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();

@Test
public void test1() {     
    String patter1 = "/com/abc/def/x.html/";
    String patter2 = "/com/**/abc/def/x.html/";
    String path1 = "/com/abc/def/x.html/";
    String path2 = "/com/abc/def/x.html";

    assertTrue(matcher.match(patter1, path1));
    assertTrue(matcher.match(patter2, path1));
    assertFalse(matcher.match(patter1, path2));
    assertTrue(matcher.match(patter2, path2));
  }
}
```

while, both patter1 and patter2 last char is '**/**', and path1 last char also is  '**/**', but path2 not.

path1 can match both patter1 and patter2
but path2 only math patter2, NOT patter1, why?

Answer (score 1):

Well, You have made a very good point. It is the way it is(That is how it is designed).

But may be I can give some internal details. This is what I found after I debugged `AntPathMatcher::match`.

***Reason why `matcher.match(patter1, path2)` is false***  ===> `/` is considered as the default path separator. So what `match` method does internally is to split it using `/` as the separator and see if all the tokens match. But in the end there is a comparision line like this

```
return (pattern.endsWith(this.pathSeparator) == path.endsWith(this.pathSeparator));
```

Which is basically checking if both pattern and path end with `/` or not. Hence you are getting false.

***Reason why `matcher.match(patter2, path2)` is true***  ===> Well things get tricky when there is a  wildcard  `**` involved.  If there is a wildcard involved then the logic is such that, initially the tokens are matched till `**` is encountered. Once found, it checks for tokens from the last till the last occurence of `**`. In this case there is no check for trailing `/`. That is the main reason for this to work.

May be it is a bug. So the reason this case works is because of wildcard character.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So matcher.match(patter2, path2) is true  because it didn't check whether the two string end with same pathSeparator  when there is a wildcar ** involved while matcher.match(patter1, path2)  did check. But I don't understand why it didn't check in this situation

Comment: As i said in the last statement. May be it is a bug.